# Stretch Grid to window size

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, size, stretch

I've just started learning C# WPF with a basic empty project and I want to make a grid, with a background image, which stretches exactly over the window.

The way it is now, the grid stretches, but not the way I want it. For example my background image is 1000x1000px and my window size is 1700x1200px so the grid stretches to 1200x1200px (it keeps the aspect ratio of the image. I don't want this, I want it simply to stretch all over the window.

Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="Backgammon.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="auto" Width="auto">
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="510" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Source="C:\Users\Edy\Pictures\cool-wallpapers1.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Image>
    <Button Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,12,12" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="145" Click="button1_Click" ClipToBounds="False">Connect</Button>
    <ListBox Margin="12,12,0,149" Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="225" />
</Grid>
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try

```
<Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, 
              RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType = {x:Type Window}}}" 
      Height="{Binding ActualHeight, 
              RelativeSource ={RelativeSource AncestorType = {x:Type Window}}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it figured out. It was the `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>` that messed things up for me. Deleted that and it worked :)

Comment: Yes, column to be stretched should not have `Width="auto"`.