# Add Grid RowDefinitions With Control Dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

First, let me state my intentions. This is the final result I am looking for.

[Mockup Of Intent http://s18.postimg.org/x818zbfbb/image.png](http://s18.postimg.org/x818zbfbb/image.png)

The output of my code, however, fails to achieve this. Here's what I did. This is my MainWindow XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="" Height="200" Width="400"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Name="ViewData">
    <Grid Name="splMain" Background="{StaticResource GreyGradient}"></Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is the C# code for the dynamic `RowDefitions` creation:

```
private void ViewImgData(SubPod subPod)
        {
            var wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.Navigate(subPod.Image.Src);
            var rowDefinition = new RowDefinition();
            rowDefinition.Height = GridLength.Auto;
            splMain.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDefinition);
            Grid.SetRow(wb, 0); 
            ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).splMain.Children.Add(wb);

        }
```

This I am calling from over here. It is guaranteed that this `foreach` loop would run more than once. **However, my output window shows only 1 image instead of 2 or more, that too not taking up the whole space of the Window.**

```
foreach (SubPod subPod in pod.SubPods)
                        {
                            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                             DispatcherPriority.Background,
                             new Action(() => ViewImgData(subPod)));
                        }
```

Where have I mistaken? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you create new `RowDefinition` each time but then you put each `WebBrowser` always in the 0 row

Comment: Really? Looks like you have a basic problem with your webbrowser based logic since you post a new question having the same problem, just with another container... Besides that, don´t put each element into the 0th row

Comment: @Ben Sorry, but I am kinda in a fix here. I am unable to get the containers to work and DockPanel is not an option according to my instructor.

Comment: If you really just want to show images, why not use the <Image> Control? Just curious.

Comment: @Ben Instructor guidelines. And I can't ask him what you just asked without risking my grades :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add new rows, but place the new webbrowser component in the 0th row.
Try

```
Grid.SetRow(wb, splMain.RowDefinitions.Count-1);
```

instead, since you need to place new content in the new row.

EDIT:
To fit the grid height and width try adding this to your splMain grid

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"
```

see also [Stretch Grid to window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521841/stretch-grid-to-window-size)

Comment: Works! But is there a way to fill the whole window? This seems to cover only the top half.  I have set `VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` but not working.

Comment: Does the grid fill the whole window? Maybe you generate to much rows with "empty" webbrowsers? How big are your webbrowsers? Maybe they just don´t fill the grid?

Comment: The grid fills just the top half. The webbrowsers should fill the grid and empty webbrowsers are not the culprit. any other suggestion?