# XAML WPF how to stretch the frame to fill the window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The title it's quite descriptive.
I have the frame of a page which I want to stretch to fill the window.
I'd be thankful if someone could give me a heads up on what I should be doing.
Here is my XAML code:

```
<Page x:Class="testWPF.CameraPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:LightBuzz.Vitruvius.Controls;assembly=LightBuzz.Vitruvius"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      Height="1920" Width="1080"
      d:DesignHeight="1920" d:DesignWidth="1080"
      Title="Camera"
      Unloaded="Page_Unloaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <controls:KinectViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="viewer" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Frame HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Name="frame2" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Asked and answered in below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521841/stretch-grid-to-window-size

Comment: You probably want to have the Frame in the second row, so set `Grid.Row="1"`.

Comment: @Clemens still not working, it's now on top of the window, covering half of the top side. T__T

Comment: Perhaps try removing the Width and Height attributes from your page.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Grid.RowSpan="2"` to the `Frame`:

```
<Frame Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Name="frame2" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
```